# How to display content with html tags for reactive forms Angular

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, innerhtml, html-tag-details

Component.html

```html
<form [formGroup]="formName">
  <input formControlName="title">
</form>
```

Component.ts

```js
this.formName.patchValue({
  title : this.content
})
```

Sometimes `this.content` contains html tags like `<i>`/`<b>` tags. In that case, the tags are also displaying.
How can we achieve that particular text in italics or bold.
Example: `this.content = Solve ur doubts in (<i>StackOverflow</i>)`
Expected Output : Solve ur doubts in (*StackOverflow*)

In general, by passing this.content in [innerHTML] attribute solved the issue.
But in my case it's a reactive form and innerHtML can't be used.
Can someone suggest what can be done to get the output as **Solve ur doubts in (*StackOverflow*)**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

you can use innerHTML, exemple:

```
<div [innerHTML]="content"></div>
```

Be careful, in your patchValues, it is not an equal but a colon

```
this.formName.patchValue({ title: this.content })
```

In some cases, you will need to specify that the html is "secure". For example if it comes from an API
I advise you to make a pipe to simplify

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer, SafeHtml } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Pipe({
  name: 'safeHtml'
})
export class SafeHtmlPipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}

  transform(value: string): SafeHtml {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value);
  }
}
```

And to use :

```
<div [innerHTML]="content | safeHtml"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but as I mentioned, for reactive forms, innerHTML is not accessible.
If I use as suggested, form actions can't be performed for that varaibale.

Comment: I'm not sure this is possible directly with input and reactive form. I can only suggest that you go through a style overview:
`<form [formGroup]="formName">
    <input formControlName="title" />
</form>

<section>
    <div [innerHTML]="formName.value.title"></div>
</section>`
Or if you really want to do WYSIWYG, use a package dedicated to that.
I couldn't do better, maybe someone more knowledgeable than me will contradict me and find a solution for you.